# Crop Bitmap without memory leak

Tags: c#, function, memory-leaks, bitmap

I have a function which only crops Bitmap.

```
public static Bitmap cropImage(Bitmap FullBmp, int leftBorder, int topBorder)
{
    return FullBmp.Clone(new Rectangle(leftBorder, topBorder, FullBmp.Width, FullBmp.Height - topBorder), FullBmp.PixelFormat);
}
```

This code works, however it creates huge memory leak. With this function:
[image: Memory leak]
And without:
[image: Memory ok]

I approximately understand why this happens, but I can't fix this memory leak. I tried to use Graphics.DrawImage but without success.

Comment: do you dispose the bitmap after you are done with it? Because you are creating a copy that floats around until the garbage collector collects it. If you dispose it or use it within a using block you should be able to midigate that problem. IF you are just doing it to show it in the GUI you could also consider to just use a margin on the image box and just hide the excess, than your gpu will take car of it. Cand do that if you process the cropped image some how or store it tho

Comment: @DenisSchaf Im disposing it later in the code. I understand that there is an original bitmap and the copy. But when do I need to dispose original if function result (clone) is assigned to the original Bitmap variable? Im doing it not only to show, but also to look for items in it.

Comment: Yes of course you need to dispose it. Both the original and the clone need to be disposed. The original should be disposed when you don't need it anymore. Please show the code where you are using this and disposing.

Comment: please dont update the question to include the answer but rather accept the given answer or post your own! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are releasing the original bitmap reference without releasing resources so it will depend on GC cycle to do this.
to enforce releasing memory you should do this:

```
var baslerImg_n = ImageManipulation.cropImage(baslerImg, 0, 650);
baslerImg.Dispose();
baslerImg = baslerImg_n;
```

Comment: I will accept this answer, however it lacks disposing 'baslerImg_n'. Also in my case I used 'new Bitmap(baslerImg_n)' otherwise it didn't work